# How do we implement sqluvint action=SQLUV_QUERY_LOGS functionality for IBM DB2 vendorlib?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am looking to understand how the functionality for searching a vendor device for sqluvint with action=SQLUV_QUERY_LOGS and db2VendorGetNextObj in the IBM DB2 vendorlib library should be implemented as part of the backup and restore functionality.

There is very minimal documentation on the input/response expectations available at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=products-db2-call-sequence-vendor-apis and the sample code at https://github.com/IBM/db2-samples/blob/master/BARVendor/vendor.C does not provide any sample implementation for this.

Thanks in advance!!

Output of db2level:

> DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable:
> "db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11056" with level
> identifier "0607010F".
> Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.6.0", "s2106111000", "DYN2106111000AMD64",
> and Fix Pack "0".
> Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5".

Comment: The implementation will vary with the nature of the "device" you use for storage and the choices your implementation makes. It is up to the  implementation to decide how to store/retrieve/search the archived transaction log files. It is unclear why you think IBM would give a sample implementation.

Comment: A while ago I wrote some code which eventually was published at the link [Tool to retrieve log file using DB2 vendor API](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/tool-retrieve-log-file-using-db2-vendor-api). I don't remember the details like why I used some settings namely in that way. This code probably doesn't do what you need - it doesn't list logs, but retrieves some particular log. Nevertheless you may find this code useful...

Comment: Thanks  @mao , sorry for the delayed response. Have been looking into the vendor implementation side of things to see what I am missing. Still not entirely clear, but will continue to take a look.  Thanks Mark Barinstein for the sample code on log retrieval.

Comment: Hi @mao , I was able to proceed with the search sequence to handle searching archived transaction log files. However, am seeing some ambiguity with one scenario. When a Db2 backup is being taken, if DB2 does not find any archived transaction log files (for attaching to the backup at the end), it issues a query to the vendor. However, I do see that the db2instance comes in as a"*" . Is DB2 not aware of the instance for which the backup is being taken? Is this also state that needs to be stored at the vendor side? Thanks

Comment: please edit your question to show in plain text the full text output of the `db2level` command when run by the Db2-instance on the Db2-server.

Comment: @mao , just updated the question with the output of db2level, thanks

Comment: Suggest you open a ticket with IBM Db2 support to get the clarification on the circumstances when the sqluvint input Init_input.Db2-session.db2instance has value "*". I notice that Mark-Barinstein's code (as linked in a comment above) also explicitly sets db2instance to * for a retrieve action, so Mark may have a different suggestion. The documentation is, as you point out, minimal, although devs are apt to hide stuff away.

Comment: Hi @MarkBarinstein , as mentioned by mao , I do see that the tool to retrieve logs specifies the db2instance as "*". Is there any significance behind doing that? Without the db2instance name, can we accurately get the list of matching files since we could have potentially the same file name across two different instances.